# $(1,1,\cdots ,1)\in C \Leftrightarrow X-1 \nmid g(X)$ , cyclic code $C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

$C$ is a $q$-ary cyclic $[n,k]$-code, where $(n,q)=1$, with generator polynomial $g(X)$. Show that $(1,1,\cdots ,1)\in C \Leftrightarrow X-1 \nmid g(X)$.

I know what a generator polynomial is. I know that the cyclic code has dimension equal to $k$ so the $deg(g(X))=n-k$. So $g(X)=g_{0}+g_{1}x+\cdots+g_{n-k}x^{n-k}$, where $g_{n-k} \neq 0$ But I don't know how to use $(n,q)=1$ or how to start finding any solution.

Comment: I don't know if I am right:
$$x^{n}-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^{2}+\cdots+x^{n-1}).$$ Since g(x) is a generator polynomial so divides $x^(n)-1$ and does not have $x-1$ as a factor, it must divide $1+x+x^{2}+\cdots+x^{n-1}$. In other words, the length $n$ word consisting of all $1$'s is a codeword.

Comment: I would add the comment to the question body for it is a good start.

Comment: You need the assumption $(n,q)=1$ to prove that if $g(x)$ is a factor of $P_n(x):=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}$ then $(x-1)\nmid g(x)$. Hint: $x-1\mid P_n(x)$ if and only if $P_n(1)=0$.